# Unable to serialize Json return from WebApi for Complex Entity and Aliased fields

Tags: json, serialization, model

I need to return a Json model to my front end that includes a model with nested arrays to display a menu so not all items will have subitems.  I need to be able to rename my exposed fields and return the complex model to be consumed by in my case, the Kendo framework.

My goal is to return an object like this: (From Json.org/example)

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"$id":"2","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at ...
```

This is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication3;
using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class apimenuController : ApiController
    {
        private RiverAnalyticsEntities db = new RiverAnalyticsEntities();

        // GET api/apimenu
        public JsonResult GetRA_sysHorizontalMenu()
        {
            var items = (from i in db.RA_sysHorizontalMenu
                                           select new sysHorizontalMenuItem
                                           {

                                               Id = i.Id,
                                               text = i.shmMenuLabel,
                                               url = i.shmMenuDestination,
                                               content = i.shmMenuToolTip,
                                               subitems = i.RA_sysHorizontalSubMenu
                                           });
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { items} };

        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool RA_sysHorizontalMenuExists(int id)
        {
            return db.RA_sysHorizontalMenu.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Model for the primary object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class sysHorizontalMenuItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }

       // public ICollection<sysHorizontalSubItems> sysHorizontalSubItems { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RA_sysHorizontalSubMenu> subitems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am using the .Net scaffolded code for the subitems like this:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WebApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class RA_sysHorizontalSubMenu
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> shsMenuId { get; set; }
        public string shsMenuLabel { get; set; }
        public string shsMenuToolTip { get; set; }
        public string shsMenuHelp { get; set; }
        public string shsMenuLong { get; set; }
        public string shsMenuDestination { get; set; }

        public virtual RA_sysHorizontalMenu RA_sysHorizontalMenu { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem.  I realized that if I construct my relationships in SQL correctly and allow EntityFramework to handle the rest all I needed was a nested linq query.  Linq is surprisingly flexible once you understand the rules.

Here is my solution: (I included the entire class to explain where I implemented it)
Considering I am new any comments,and criticism are welcome so feel free to share your knowledge.  Thanks very much.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult getmenus()
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            var menuitems = (from i in db.RA_sysHorizontalMenu
                             select new 
                             {
                                 Id = i.Id,
                                 text = i.shmMenuLabel,
                                 content = i.shmMenuToolTip,
                                 url = i.shmMenuDestination,
                                 items = (from s in i.RA_sysHorizontalSubMenu
                                        select new 
                                        {
                                           Id = s.Id,
                                           text = s.shsMenuLabel,
                                           content = s.shsMenuToolTip,
                                           url = s.shsMenuDestination
                                        })
                             }).ToArray();

            return Json(menuitems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```